# Android touchEvent: Lifting while moving

Tags: android, touch

A specific method needs to be called whenever a gesture ends. Currently, I'm using an if statement to see if a MotionEvent is `ACTION_UP` to do this. However, I've discovered that if I lift my finger while swiping quickly, the MotionEvent is not an `ACTION_UP`, but an `ACTION_MOVE`. It only works properly if I lift while the finger is not moving.

Any suggestions or alternative solutions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: problem solved

Comment: You Answer your own question by the Post Your Answer button at the bottom of this page. And then you Accept the Answer with the White Check Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out what was wrong. I was using some booleans to prevent ConcurrentModificationExceptions when onTouchEvent modifies a list of objects that my renderer was also drawing. Turns out that this was ending the method early half the time. I ended up synchronizing the lists, and now it works fine.